# MySQL view: convert unix timestamp to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I convert timestamps in a MySQL View?

I have a MySQL View for data exchange between 2 different software tools. 
The original table is a unix timestamp as `int(11)`.  The other software expects a DATETIME.

I have a VIEW like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `myView` AS 
select 
date_format(from_unixtime(`myUnixTimestamp`),_utf8'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
AS `Date-Entered`
from ...
```

This VIEW statement creates a varchar(24) - which is better than nothing as it can be converted - but the conversion makes some problems.

Is there any way to create a DATETIME field instead of a VARCHAR with the view?

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the value to `datetime`:

```
-- print a UNIX timestamp (as returned by NOW()) as DATETIME
SELECT CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS DATETIME );
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers, I tried some combinations, and this one worked (so easy, its a shame...):

```
CREATE VIEW `myView` AS 
select 
from_unixtime(`myUnixTimestamp`)
AS `Date-Entered`
from ...
```

View Structure shows: Date-Entered, type: datetime

Answer (score -1):

try

```
CREATE VIEW `myView` AS 
select 
FROM_UNIXTIME([unix timestamp],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
AS `Date-Entered`
from ...
```